# failed calling webhook inferenceservice.kfserving-webhook-server.defaulter , x509 certificate error in kubeflow

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubeflow

I am new to kubeflow.
I have installed it on a azure machine via minikube.
Whenever I am trying to spawn a notebook I encounter the error as shown in the the following diagram.

[image]

i.e rror from server (InternalError): error when creating "something.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "inferenceservice.kfserving-webhook-server.defaulter": Post https://kfserving-webhook-server-service.kubeflow.svc:443/mutate-inferenceservices?timeout=30s . x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0

Can someone help?

Comment: are you using service mesh ? istio it's looks like it is mutual TLS error while service is trying to connect to another service.

Comment: @HarshManvar Yes istio is being used. I just got the output for kubectl get pods -n istio-system.

Comment: Then it might be mTLS issue

Comment: some of the pod status is node-affinity and are not up. I think that may be the cause? @HarshManvar

Comment: Please check service you are trying access is up and also check the policy in istio for mTLS

Comment: AFAIK some of the istio features are not compatible with minikube, as for mTLS issues please review this page: https://istio.io/latest/faq/security/

Comment: What istio and k8s version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with anything compiled with Golang 1.15.  What version of Minikube are you running?  That might be the issue.  See info on the kubernetes 1.19 release.  I know you're running Minikube but maybe related.

Kubernetes is now built with golang 1.15.0-rc.1.
The deprecated, legacy behavior of treating the CommonName field on X.509 serving certificates as a host name when no Subject Alternative Names are present is now disabled by default. It can be temporarily re-enabled by adding the value x509ignoreCN=0 to the GODEBUG environment variable. (#93264, @justaugustus) [SIG API Machinery, Auth, CLI, Cloud Provider, Cluster Lifecycle, Instrumentation, Network, Node, Release, Scalability, Storage and Testing]

Answer (score 1):

we had a similar problem, and found the solution in [this Issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4763):

```sh
kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfigurations inferenceservice.serving.kubeflow.org && kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfigurations inferenceservice.serving.kubeflow.org && kubectl delete po kfserving-controller-manager-0 -n kfserving-system
```